# How to represent a many-to-many relationship where the join table contains the identifying type

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Running Grails 3.3.10, I have a Product entity which has a many-to-many relationship with a Message table on 2 separate fields (product.type1Messages and product.type2Messages) and the "type" field is located in the join table in the database.

Is it possible to use mappings to get the right messages into the right collections?

Please find my code below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `productmessage` (
  `productId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `messageId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productId`,`messageId`,`type`)
);
```

```java
class Product {

    static hasMany = [ type1Messages: Message, type2Messages: Message ]

    static mappedBy = [ type1Messages: "type1Product", type2Messages: "type2Product" ]

    static mapping = {
        type1Messages joinTable: [name: 'productmessage', key: 'productId', column: 'messageId']
        type2Messages joinTable: [name: 'productmessage', key: 'productId', column: 'messageId']
    }
}
```

```java
class Message {

    Product type1Product
    Product type2Product

    static mapping = {
        type1Product column: "productId"
        type2Product column: "productId"
    }
}
```

I need my `product.type1Messages` to only contain those with type 1 in the join table and `product.type2Messages` to contain those with type 2. Is that possible and, if so, what do I need to add?

**Edit**
I just realised that I may have confused things by stating many-to-many relationship and then simplifying the example to only display one-to-many. Note that my problem is with the type being in the join table as opposed to how to represent the many-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some special class for this. Something like this:

```
abstract class ProductMessage {
    Product product
    Message message
}

class Type1ProductMessage extends ProductMessage {

}

class Type2ProductMessage extends ProductMessage {

}
class Product {

    static hasMany = [ type1Messages: Type1ProductMessage, type2Messages: Type2ProductMessage ]
}
```

If you do not want to play with abstract classes you can make the first one as main and extend the second one from first.

In the DB it will be mapped as:

```
'id'
'product_id'
'message_id'
'class'
```